# Disable link decoration on a logo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.nav-d a{
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;

}
.nav-d a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #262262;
}
.nav-d a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #262262;
}
```

```html
<div class="container nav-d" style="max-width: 1134px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-5" href="home.html"><img src="Logo-transparant.png" alt="Logo-transparant"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active pr-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="home.html" > Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Nieuwefietsen.html">Nieuwe fietsen</a>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="Tweedehandsfietsen.html">Tweedehands fietsen</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item pr-5">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Fietsreperatie.html">Fietsreperatie</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item pr-4">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
                 </li>
                  <li class="nav-itme pr-0" style= "border:2px solid rgb(47, 47, 112); border-radius: 250px; background-color: rgb(47, 47, 112);">
                <a class="nav-link my-link disabled ml-3 mr-2 " herf="home.html" style="color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i class="far fa-phone mr-2"></i>06 20453640</a>
                  </li>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Disable link decoration on the logo (the bottom underline decoration). i want to get rid of it i tried text-decoration: none; that didn't help.

Comment: If you get a message saying that you should add more text, because the ratio of your explanation to the amount of code you posted is off - then that does _not_ mean you should try and “work around” that, by simply copy&pasting the same thing into your question multiple times.

Comment: Try this instead `.navbar a.navbar-brand{text-decoration: none;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

You HTML Code is invalid there is not `<ul>` tag before `<li>`

```
.nav-d a.navbar-brand:hover{
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
}
```

```css
.nav-d a{
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.nav-d a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #262262;
}
.nav-d a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #262262;
}
.nav-d a.navbar-brand:hover{
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container nav-d" style="max-width: 1134px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-5" href="home.html"><img src="Logo-transparant.png" alt="Logo-transparant"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active pr-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="home.html" > Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item pr-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Nieuwefietsen.html">Nieuwe fietsen</a>
          </li>
           <li class="nav-item pr-4">
           <a class="nav-link" href="Tweedehandsfietsen.html">Tweedehands fietsen</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Fietsreperatie.html">Fietsreperatie</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item pr-4">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
           </li>
            <li class="nav-itme pr-0" style= "border:2px solid rgb(47, 47, 112); border-radius: 250px; background-color: rgb(47, 47, 112);">
          <a class="nav-link my-link disabled ml-3 mr-2 " herf="home.html" style="color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i class="far fa-phone mr-2"></i>06 20453640</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     <div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
a {
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This. That's it.

```
.nav-d a.navbar-brand:hover{border-bottom:none;}
```